# Assigning generic type to generic with AnyObject type

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics

I can easily do this using Swift's array without any compiler error:

```
let array: Array<AnyObject> = Array<String>()
```

But when I try to do the same with my custom type I get compiler error:

```
class Bar<T> { 
}

let bar: Bar<AnyObject> = Bar<String>()
```

Error is:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Bar< String>' to specified type
>   'Bar< AnyObject>'

How can I achieve the same behaviour with custom type as with native Swift's array?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that you cannot *"easily"* perform your first assignment, seemingly from `[Any]` to `[String]`: the reason why this seemingly works is that you are in fact initializing an array of `Any` elements with an **empty** array (that happens to be of type `[String]`). If you try to initialize your `Any` array with a `[String]` array that holds actual elements, you'll run into a runtime error:

```
let anyArr1: Array<Any> = Array<String>()   // = [], ok
let anyArr2: Array<Any> = []                // ok

let anyArr3: Array<Any> = [String](count: 2, repeatedValue: "foo")
    // = ["foo", "foo"], not ok
    /* fatal error: can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes */
```

In so, the comparison in your question don't really make sense. If you want to do type conversion between two array instances of different element types, you need to do this one element at a time, e.g. using `.map`:

```
let anyArr4: Array<Any> = [String](count: 2, repeatedValue: "foo").map{ $0 as Any }
print(anyArr4)
    // prints "["foo", "foo"]", ok
```

Since Swift is strongly typed, `Bar<Any>` and `Bar<String>` are, inherently, two different types. If you want to initialize one by the other, you'll have to customize your own initializer for this purpose, as simple assignment or casting between these two *different* types will fail.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I've edited my question with AnyObject instead of Any to avoid confusion. In this case there is no runtime error and casting from strings array to AnyObject's array doesn't fail. But custom type still shows me the same error as mentioned in the question.